# Applying different geom functions in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with plotting a ggplot where I need to change the geom_smooth after some point. As it is now, I'm applying smooth function for the entire serie, but the the smooth line doesn't make much sense for the period just after "xmin". So, I'm wondering if there is a way around that I could not plot geom_smooht for that mark and further.

```
library(ggplot2)

xmin <- as.Date("2012/10/08", "%Y/%m/%d") # Beginning and end of discontinuity
xmax <- as.Date("2012/11/01", "%Y/%m/%d")

data$brand <- factor(data$brand, levels = c("A","B","C", "Others", "Undecideds"))

g <- ggplot(data)
g <- g + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "#D8D8D8", alpha = .01)
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour=brand, group=interaction(brand, Event)), size=3.5)
g <- g + scale_color_manual(values=c("#0066FF","#00B206","#FF0000","#FFFFCC", "#D0D0D0"))
g <- g + geom_smooth(data=data, aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour=brand, group=interaction(brand, Event)), method="loess", size=2, se=F)
g <- g + theme(legend.position="bottom")
print(g)
```

Comment: what about putting your data object within each individual geom call? i.e geom_rect(data,aes(.... then for the geom_smooth call just subset the data for the appropriate section you wish to plot ... g+geom_smooth(data[rowsIwant, ],aes(....

Comment: @user3407340 could you provide some data?

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt an answer so that there is at least something to start here. What you want to do, I pressume, is that you are interested in plotting all points, but focus the smoothing approximation, after a data point (your `xmax`).

So here it goes:

```
library(ggplot2)

xmin <- as.Date("2012/10/08", "%Y/%m/%d") # Beginning and end of discontinuity
xmax <- as.Date("2012/11/01", "%Y/%m/%d")

# dummy attempt to create some data to start
data=data.frame(brand=rep(c("A","B","C", "Others", "Undecideds"),100), 
            Date=seq(from=as.Date("2012/01/01", "%Y/%m/%d"), to=as.Date("2012/01/01", "%Y/%m/%d")+499, by="1 day"),
            Rating=runif(500),
            Event=rep(c('Event1','Event2'),250))


data$brand <- factor(data$brand, levels = c("A","B","C", "Others", "Undecideds"))
#Let's say that the data points after xmax are FWD, and the ones before, BCK
data$range=ifelse(data$Date>=xmax,"FWD","BCK")

ggplot() +
geom_rect(data=data,aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "#D8D8D8", alpha = .01) +
geom_point(data=data,aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour=brand, group=interaction(brand, Event)), size=3.5) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("#0066FF","#00B206","#FF0000","#FFFFCC", "#D0D0D0")) +
# Smooth only the fwd ones
geom_smooth(data=data[data$range=="FWD",], aes(x=Date, y=Rating, colour=brand, group=interaction(brand, Event)), method="loess", size=2, se=F) +
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

The result is this:

[image]

Is this towards the right direction?